# about inheritance in C++, can a derived class get implemetation from base class without explicitly defining it

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

The following has the error

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall C::Foo(void)" (?Foo@C@@UAEXXZ)

so basically `C::Test()` cannot inherit implementation of `B::Test()` automatically and we have to explicitly write it everytime in C++?

```
class A
{

public:  
    virtual void Foo()=0;
    virtual void Test()=0;

};

class B: public A 
{
public: 
    virtual void Foo();
    virtual void Test()=0;

};

void B::Foo()
{

}



class C: public B
{
public:
    void Foo();
    void Test();
};



void C::Test()
{
}
```

Comment: At least one derived class must implement a pure virtual function declared in a base class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your derived class declares a virtual method from a parent class, as `C` does with `void Foo()`, then it must implement it too. If you want to inherit `B`'s implementation, then don't declare `void Foo()` in `C`.

```
class C: public B
{
public:
    void Test();
};
```

Comment: Also you should have the virtual tag on void Test(), and (as a personal preference) I always use the override keyword when overriding a virtual function. Neither of these are required to get your code to run, but they do make it more obvious what you are doing and forces additional compiler checks.

Answer (score 0):

You have made A::Test() pure virtual, so the child class must implement it.

That is what the `A::Test()=0` syntax means.

If you remove `=0`, and provide an implementation in the parent class, you are not required to implement it in the child classes.

Answer (score 0):

You only need a pure virtual function in your abstract base class, for dynamic binding.

Edit: I'm pretty sure you need to implement the all of the functions, even if they're empty. That's why it wouldn't compile for you.

```
class A
{
    public:  
    virtual void Foo()=0;
    virtual void Test()=0;
};

class B: public A
{
    public: 
    void Foo();
    void Test();
};

void B::Foo()
{

}
void B::Test()
{

}


class C: public B
{
    public:
    void Foo();
    void Test();
};


void C::Foo()
{

}
void C::Test()
{
}
```

Comment: I tested it on my linux, and I had to implement all the functions for it to compile successfully.